# Compare and remove same characters in two Strings in java then output the remaining characters as numbers

Tags: java, string

Say i have user input 2 different names. For example:

```
firstName = "Stack Overflow"
secondName = "Stack Exchange"
```

What i want to do is to compare them, which means  the word `"Stack"` would be eliminated, then the remaining String characters will output as numbers.

`"overflow"` will output as `8`, same with `"Exchange"` which should output `8`.

Is there a method that i can use? I'm just a newbie so i would appreciate a non-`array` method or some advanced Java methods.

Comment: How do you derive 8 from "overflow" and "exchange"? The length of the string?

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean by "will output as 8"

Comment: You need to have a go yourself, and ask specific questions if you get stuck. We aren't just going to write your code for you.

Comment: Sorry, yes the length of the remaining String.

Comment: and i'm not asking for the codes. i need the methods. i tried different String methods liks compareTo(). indexOf etc..

Comment: So you want to find a common prefix between two strings, then output the lengths of each string with the common prefix removed?

Comment: yes ulmangt! thats exactly what i want. what method should i use?

Answer (score 1):

Some methods that are of use:

- [`String.substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring)
- [`String.equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`String.compareToIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Iterations over the length of the different characters would give you a number, but I'm uncertain if you want the longer String or the shorter String to output.  (In either event, using a loop would help.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try iterating through the characters in the two strings, comparing them step by step until you find a character which differs. At that point, you just return the length of the string minus the number of characters in the common prefix.

Try something like this (code not tested, you'll probably have to do some tweaking -- also this only returns the length-minus-prefix of the first argument string):

```
public int stringLength( String s1, String s2 )
{
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < Math.min( s1.length(), s2.length() ) ; i++ )
  {
    if ( s1.charAt( i ) != s2.charAt( i )
    {
      return s1.length() - i;
    }
  }

  return s1.length();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand , you want to remove Common Elements form both String: If so here is solution:
        String str1 = "Stack Overflow";
        String str2 = "Stack Exchange";

```
    ArrayList arr1 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList arr2 = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
            arr1.add(str1.charAt(i));
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
            arr2.add(str2.charAt(i));
        }
        arr1.retainAll(arr1);

     java.util.List<ArrayList> chars = Arrays. asList(arr1);
     String str = chars.toString().replace(",","");
 return str;
```